# CPU caching understanding

Tags: c++, performance, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I tested the next code with Google Benchmark framework to measure memory access latency with different array sizes:

```
int64_t MemoryAccessAllElements(const int64_t *data, size_t length) {
    for (size_t id = 0; id < length; id++) {
        volatile int64_t ignored = data[id];
    }
    return 0;
}
int64_t MemoryAccessEvery4th(const int64_t *data, size_t length) {
    for (size_t id = 0; id < length; id += 4) {
        volatile int64_t ignored = data[id];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I get next results (the results are averaged by google benchmark, for big arrays, there is about ~10 iterations and much more work performed for smaller one):

[image: Benchmark results]

There is a lot of different stuff happened on this picture and unfortunately, I can't explain all changes in the graph.

I tested this code on single core CPU with next caches configuration:

```
CPU Caches:                                                                                              
  L1 Data 32K (x1), 8 way associative
  L1 Instruction 32K (x1), 8 way associative
  L2 Unified 256K (x1), 8 way associative
  L3 Unified 30720K (x1), 20 way associative
```

At this pictures we can see many changes in graph behavior:

1. There is a spike after 64 bytes array size that can be explained by the fact, that cache line size is 64 bytes long and with an array of size more than 64 bytes we experience one more L1 cache miss (which can be categorized as a compulsory cache miss)
2. Also, the latency increasing near the cache size bounds that is also easy to explain - at this moment we experience capacity cache misses

But there is a lot of questions about results that I can't explain:

1. Why latency for the `MemoryAccessEvery4th` decreasing after array exceeded ~1024 bytes?
2. Why we can see another peak for the `MemoryAccessAllElements` around 512 bytes? It is an interesting point because at this moment we started to access more than one set of cache lines (8 * 64 bytes in one set). But is it really caused by this event and if it is than how it can be explained?
3. Why we can see latency increasing after passing the L2 cache size while benchmarking `MemoryAccessEvery4th` but there is no such difference with the `MemoryAccessAllElements`?

I've tried to compare my results with the results from [gallery of processor cache effects](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/) and [what every programmer should know about memory](https://akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf), but I can't fully describe my results with reasoning from this articles.

Can someone help me to understand the internal processes of CPU caching?

**UPD:**
I use the following code to measure performance of memory access:

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
using namespace benchmark;
void InitializeWithRandomNumbers(long long *array, size_t length) {
    auto random = Random(0);
    for (size_t id = 0; id < length; id++) {
        array[id] = static_cast<long long>(random.NextLong(0, 1LL << 60));
    }
}
static void MemoryAccessAllElements_Benchmark(State &state) {
    size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(state.range(0));
    auto array = new long long[size];
    InitializeWithRandomNumbers(array, size);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        DoNotOptimize(MemoryAccessAllElements(array, size));
    }
    delete[] array;
}
static void CustomizeBenchmark(benchmark::internal::Benchmark *benchmark) {
    for (int size = 2; size <= (1 << 24); size *= 2) {
        benchmark->Arg(size);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(MemoryAccessAllElements_Benchmark)->Apply(CustomizeBenchmark);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

You can find slightly different examples in [the repository](https://github.com/Umqra/SimdLecture/tree/cpp/cpp/sum-in-array), but actually the basic approach for the benchmark in the question is same.

Comment: The cache hierarchy is not all you need to consider. The CPUs prefetcher is also important.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, it is. I know a little about it. But I thought that prefetcher mainly relates to the absolute values of the latency (instead of the L2 cache hit latency prefetcher allows us to access memory faster because fetch to the cache performed earlier). But I can't understand how prefetcher can explain the difference in the derivative of the graphs.

Comment: I didn't say it could explain anything. I merely pointed out that it is important and does influence your numbers. Just information. No explanation.

Comment: The y-axis is basically latency per byte, right? In the initial phase the latency per byte will be higher if only the first bytes of a cache line will be accessed because of the probable miss (after the first access misses, the rest go to the cache directly). This seems to repeat 2 times, the third spikes (miss) is probably enough for the CPU to trigger the L1 prefetchers and the latency/B normalizes. When we get into the L2 zone, the L2 prefetchers can keep up with the 4 elements stride of the `MemoryAccessEvery4th` function. After that the L3 zone is normalized again ...

Comment: ... either the eventual L3 prefetchers can keep up with the pace from the core or the graph has not enough resolution to show the spikes again).

Comment: Include your full benchmark program and the compiler flags and compiler used to compile it.

Comment: @Nikita - I'm willing to analyze, but you need the full program, since the small size effects may be related to the surrounding code.

Comment: This code doesn't measure latency, more like bandwdith. It's reasonable that the execution time is too small for the case where the size is less than 2^15 and the variation across runs could be too high for the average to be meaningful. Also without vectorization, the max required bandwdith here is only 8 b/c, which can easily be sustained by all cache levels. It makes sense that the bandwdith is about the same for all cache levels. This should be the case also with SSE-level vecorization. Show the assembly code and mention the CPU model and main memory configuration.

Comment: Have you tried doing just loads, instead of all those `volatile` stores?  Once per 4k page you'll get a load that 4k-aliases with a store, delaying it some.  IDK if that's significant.  The extra instructions that need to execute for the stores will slow down the fast loops some, decreasing the measured difference between L1d vs. lower-bandwidth caches when your stride is large enough for bandwidth to be an issue.

Comment: I don’t believe at all that you’re measuring what you think you do. The only way to benchmark this is to write the load loop in assembly, I think. You at least need to look at what the compiler compiled your code to at assembly level, and ensure that the compiler has read your mind correctly. I think that such benchmarks are pointless since you should be using the data for something. Add it to a variable (maybe a few different variables to cut on data dependencies) and return the result, or something like that. Compared to memory accesses, the adds are free.